# How do I plot a curved surface in matlab?

Tags: matlab, surface

I am trying to make a  cut out of a pipe and I want to make a curved surface to represent the outside of the pipe. However when I plot the surface I only get the diagonal of the surface instead of the surface itself. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
r = 0:0.1:3;
z = 0:0.1:10;  
[rr, zz] = meshgrid(r,z); 

% set cut planes angles
theta1 = 0;
theta2 = pi*135/180;
nt = 101;  % angle resolution

figure(1);
clf; 

t3 = linspace(theta1, (theta2 - 2*pi), nt);
[rr3, tt3] = meshgrid(r,t3);

% Create curved surface
xx5 = r(end) * cos(tt3);
yy5 = r(end) * sin(tt3);
h5 = surface(xx5, yy5,zz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mesh-grid you created is based on theta and the radius. However, the radius is constant for the outside of the pipe so instead it should be based on theta and z since those are the two independent variables defining the grid. Based on this reasoning I believe the following is what you're after.

```
r = 0:0.1:3;
z = 0:0.1:10;  

% set cut planes angles
theta1 = 0;
theta2 = pi*135/180;
nt = 101;  % angle resolution

figure(1);
clf; 

% create a grid over theta and z
t3 = linspace(theta1, (theta2 - 2*pi), nt);
[tt3, zz3] = meshgrid(t3, z);
% convert from cylindical to Cartesian coordinates
xx5 = r(end) * cos(tt3);
yy5 = r(end) * sin(tt3);
% plot surface
h5 = surface(xx5, yy5, zz3, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

% extra stuff to make plot prettier
axis vis3d
axis equal
view(3)
camzoom(0.7);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `surf` with `surf(xx5, yy5, zz)`. Is this what you are looking for?

[image: surf plot]